# Selenium test fails "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

So when I am trying to start the latest Firefox with an extension from the store I run into following issue:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

The program '[15388] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Am I doing something wrong there?
The problem is happening since firefox version 45 i think.

And yes I am aware that you can use an existing profile, but the performance is going downhill with that approach.

So if there is somebody who could help me out with this then i would be very grateful.

```
string ex = @"C:\extensions\speaktome@mozilla.com.xpi";
FirefoxOptions option = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension(ex);
option.Profile = profile;
WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);   Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Expected: Driver starts with extension enabled.

Actual: you get exception about wrong datetime.

Comment: seems like this would be when creating/calling DateTime.  Are you sure it's happening in this part of your code?

Comment: It is happening as the instance is trying to apply all the settings set of the options object. I never use any datetime in this code sample as it is the bare minimum to get it running.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea about how to tackle such an issue? Thank you

Comment: Did you fix the issue? I am getting the same error.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The only way that persistently works is to create a new firefox profile using the cmd command "firefox.exe -p". That opens the profile manager where you can create a new profile. from there you reference the profile using the profile and profile manager methods to add them to your options variable.

Comment: Alternatively you can use Microsoft's UI AUtomation API to add the extension as a debugging extension. I know this is pretty overkill, but it was the only stable way to add an extension automatically and test it.